# iOS getting Linker error on Build

Tags: ios

I'm getting this error whenever I try to build.

```
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what to do. It was working, I added a symbol #define in a class, and then it got that error. I tried deleting that to no avail.

Yes, I've seen the post about this with about 10 answers, none of the answers have seemed to help.

Thanks for any help, if you need any more information just ask please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I made a very stupid mistake. I somehow added an
`@implemention` to a class that I already had one of. I have no idea how I did it.